# "A hit with" has the preposition "with" – why not "to"?

Tags: prepositions

I am confused about the use of these prepositions.

Can someone explain how to use them in sentences?

I think "a hit to [somebody]" is more comfortable to me.

> This product is a hit **with** women.

vs.

> This product is a hit **to** women.

Comment: Could you add some more context, such as what you think that this sentence means and what research you've done?

Comment: aha ... example ... that products will be a hit with woman.

Comment: What definition of "hit" are you referring to?  Do you mean "hit" as a noun meaning successful, as in, "That movie was a hit," or do you mean hit as in "to strike something or someone?"

Comment: That means a success.  is it diffrent meaning between 'Thay will be a hit to woman' and Thay will be a hit with woman' ?

Comment: Also, prepositions are one of the most arbitrary segments of the language. it can be very hard for a non-native speaker to pick the correct one for a desired meaning, and the use of a different one may change the meaning drastically (as in this case; a "hit with" is very different than "a hit to").

Answer (score 1):

Well, *to* is just wrong.  The product is a hit *among* women -- that is, it found popularity with women.  A hit "to" women would mean that in the judgement of women, it would be popular generally. "To women, this looks like it will be a hit."

Answer (score 0):

This product is a (big) hit with women.
This song is a big hit.
One could say, this product will likely be a hit to those looking for an easier way to learn a language. I still would probably use "with", however.